# Cisco ASA 5505 Random Crash

Tags: networking, cisco

From time to time, my office ASA will become unresponsive to console/ssh and drop all incoming/outgoing packets. The ASA will essentially crash. I have no idea why it does this all of a sudden, but it's been working fine for over 2 years. Our office has grown in size and the ASA has scaled to meet all of our needs via port forwarding/vpn tunneling/acl manager, however I'm thinking it's a memory issue or something that is bringing the ASA to it's knee's and eventually to a halt. The show version states that we're on 8.2.(1), which I am in the process of switching to 8.2.(5), however I don't really see this as a fix, as 8.2.(1) is what we've always used and it's never been an issue before. Is this something that any of you have seen or witnessed before? Is this a common symptom of old age? This happens randomly... Sometimes the ASA will go 1 day before crashing, sometimes 3 days, right now we're on day 3, I expect it to crash some time tonight.

Answer (score 1):

In my experience of Cisco equipment when they start doing this, you have a bad stick of memory. Especially if it been working for for a long time. Making use of Cisco logging features to a syslog server usually helps you catch these. You can also log locally to the system, but you will lose this data after reboot.

Comment: Replace the RAM. It's cheap.